# tring to take read only and write protect of flash drive

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

I have a 125 GB flash drive that is read only and when i take that off then it goes to write protected. and goes back and forth between the two how can i fix it so it wont be read only and take the write protection off at same time. I have win 7 HP on dell Optiplex 3010 8 GB ram and 500 GB hard drive. i still looking on line for a answer.  I have used coomand prompt as administrator and took the read only off then when i try to format then it say's it write protected.

Comment: what kind of flashdrive is it?

Comment: Most flash drives will go into permanent write-protection to prevent data loss if it finds any issues in itself. This happened to me after I washed my SanDisk pen drive thrice. Or you may have used up all its write cycles.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the following steps will solve this kind of problem:

- Open command line as an administrator.
- type: `diskpart`
- `list disk`
- `select disk x` where x is the number of your pendrive
- `attributes disk`
- If *read-only* is yes, type: `attributes disk clear readonly`

source: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/format-write-protected-usb-flash-drive/

If this doesn't solve your problem, I suggest trying the [Apacer USB3.0 Repair Tool](http://us.apacer.com/support/download/result/3,8,0,)